# Can I decrypt files hijacked by BitCryptor ransomware?

Tags: virus-removal

BitCryptor has encrypted my files. I have backups of mostly all my files. But I'm curious if I can decrypt my files without paying the ransom.

[image]

Comment: Sorry but there's no way I'm following a link to an obfuscated URL in a question that's asking about ransomware.

Comment: @DavidRicherby - the URL is a picture, it's safe. OP: Without backups = no chance.

Comment: It's unlikely you can access your files without paying to decrypt them. The original files are destroyed and the encryption used as stated in their own text is AES-256 which isn't crack-able. This is a new variant of Cryptolocker. You can read more on the bitdefender site:    http://labs.bitdefender.com/2013/10/cryptolocker-ransomware-makes-a-bitcoin-wallet-per-victim/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Excel,word,pdf files got encrypted by ransomware](http://superuser.com/questions/723600/excel-word-pdf-files-got-encrypted-by-ransomware)?

Comment: Not a duplicate. Completely different ransomware.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I remove malicious spyware, malware, adware, viruses, trojans or rootkits from my PC?](http://superuser.com/questions/100360/how-can-i-remove-malicious-spyware-malware-adware-viruses-trojans-or-rootkit)

Answer (score 1):

Small chance it's related (but the screenshot [looks alike](https://noransom.kaspersky.com/static/convault-decrypt-manual.pdf)) and even then: very small chance this will help. But the Dutch government and Kaspersky Lab have found some decryption keys for "CoinVault ransomware" that is worthwhile to know about; see https://noransom.kaspersky.com:

> Are you a [ransomware](https://blog.kaspersky.com/ransomware-cyber-extortion/) victim? The National High Tech Crime Unit (NHTCU) of the Netherlands’ police, the Netherlands’ National Prosecutors Office and Kaspersky Lab have been working together to fight the [CoinVault](https://securelist.com/blog/virus-watch/67699/a-nightmare-on-malware-street/) ransomware  campaign. During our joint investigation we have been able to obtain data that can help you to decrypt  the files being held hostage on your PC. We provide both decryption keys and the decryption application. For more information please see this [how-to](https://noransom.kaspersky.com/static/convault-decrypt-manual.pdf). Please note that this is an ongoing investigation and new keys will be added in the future.

Just in case in the future more keys are recovered: when copying the encrypted files also make sure you copy the Bitcoin wallet address, as that will be needed to search for decryption keys.

Comment: @Arjian - Sadly.  Coinvault and this ransomware is different enough that finding decryption keys for Coinvault won't be helpful to the user.

Comment: Also, @Ramhound, only a limited number of keys have been recovered. (Still then, it's good to make future visitors aware of the small chance, though I guess victims of new hijackings will not benefit from keys that were found in the past either...)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is no way to decrypt files encrypted by BitCryptor. This is a CoinVault variant that uses AES encryption.  The keys are generated and stored on the C2 server.

I did a full writeup on this ransomware today:

http://www.bleepingcomputer.com/forums/t/575991/bitcryptor-ransomware-in-the-wild-from-the-same-creators-as-coinvault/